# How to use java socialauth in a stateless environment? (without the need to store SocialAuthManager in session)

Tags: api, session, socialauth

I am developing a stateless RESTFul API based on JavaEE 6 and it is important not to store anything in the session.

I am using socialauth java based social auth provider.

I would like to know if there is a way to rebuid SocialAuthManager after a successful authentication without having to retrieve it from the session as documentation explains:

```
session.setAttribute("authManager", manager);
```

And then:

```
SocialAuthManager manager = (SocialAuthManager)session.getAttribute("authManager");
```

I want to avoid this. 
I would like to do something like this:

```
SocialAuthManager manager = new SocialAuthManager(PARAMS TO REBUILD PREVIOUS AUTH WORKFLOW);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing social auth with 4.10 version of this lib. 
After user get redirection url and is authorized, then I do connection to social service by this way:

```
 AccessGrant accessGrant = manager.createAccessGrant(network.getId(), params);
 Optional<Profile> profile = Optional.ofNullable(manager.connect(accessGrant).getUserProfile());

 manager.disconnectProvider(network.getId());
```

Where params - params from request of success callback API. After getting user profile I disconnect manager for reusing it. Also be aware of concurrency when using this method.